# Instantiate and apply generic method with unknown generic type - Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to instantiate an object with an unknown generic type and then apply a generic method to it. Here is where I stand :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BarIf bar = newRandomBarImpl();

    Foo foo1 = newFooBar(bar.getClass()); // warning
    Foo<?> foo2 = newFooBar(bar.getClass()); // error
    Foo<? extends BarIf> foo3 = newFooBar(bar.getClass()); // error

    foo1.doSomething(bar); // warning
    foo2.doSomething(bar); // error
    foo3.doSomething(bar); // error
}

static <T extends FooIf<S>, S extends BarIf> T newFooBar(Class<S> barClass){}

static <T extends BarIf> T newRandomBarImpl(){}

interface FooIf<T extends BarIf>
{
    public void doSomething(T t);
}

interface BarIf{}

class Foo<T extends BarIf> implements FooIf<T>
{
    public void doSomething(T t){}
}
```

The strange thing is that for foo2 and foo3, the newFooBar() method returns FooIf rather than Foo. I guess the type inference is messy. But I can't pass the method generic parameters since I don't know the Bar type.

What I would need is `Foo<bar.getClass()>`. Is there a way to do it?

I tried using TypeToken but I end up with a T type rather than the actual Bar type. Any chance using that?

Comment: Why don't you declare the variables as `FooIf<?>` instead of `Foo<?>`?

Comment: Because I want to apply methods that may not be declared in FooIf but only in Foo. That's why I'm using generic methods in the first place.

Comment: Why haven't you used type casts?

Comment: How can I cast to `Foo<bar.getClass()>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a declaration like

```
static <T extends BarIf> T newRandomBarImpl(){}
```

is nonsense. It basically says “whatever the *caller* substitutes for `T`, the method will return it”. In other words, you can write

```
ArbitraryTypeExtendingBarIf x=newRandomBarImpl();
```

without getting a compiler warning. Obviously, that can’t work. `newRandomBarImpl()` doesn’t know anything about `ArbitraryTypeExtendingBarIf`. The method name suggests that you actually want to express that `newRandomBarImpl()` can return an arbitrary implementation of `BarIf`, but that’s an unnecessary use of Generics,

```
BarIf newRandomBarImpl(){}
```

already expresses that this method can return an arbitrary subtype of `BarIf`. In fact, since `BarIf` is an abstract type, this method *must* return a subtype of `BarIf` and it’s nowhere specified which one it will be.

The same applies to the declaration

```
static <T extends FooIf<S>, S extends BarIf> T newFooBar(Class<S> barClass){}
```

It also claims that the caller can choose which implementation of `FooIf` the method will return. The correct declaration would be

```
static <S extends BarIf> FooIf<S> newFooBar(Class<S> barClass){}
```

as the method decides which implementation of `FooIf` it will return, not the caller.

---

Regarding your other attempts to deal with `FooIf`, you can’t work this way using a type parametrized with a wildcard, nor can you fix it using Reflection. But you can write *generic* code using a type parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BarIf bar = newRandomBarImpl();
    performTheAction(bar.getClass(), bar);
}
static <T extends BarIf> void performTheAction(Class<T> cl, BarIf obj) {
    FooIf<T> foo=newFooBar(cl);
    foo.doSomething(cl.cast(obj));
}
static <S extends BarIf> FooIf<S> newFooBar(Class<S> barClass){}
static BarIf newRandomBarImpl(){}

interface FooIf<T extends BarIf> {
    public void doSomething(T t);
}
interface BarIf{}
```

The method `performTheAction` is generic, in other words, works with an unknown type expressed as type parameter `T`. This method can be invoked with an unknown type `? extends BarIf` as demonstrated in the `main` method.

However, keep in mind, that every reference to a type `X` implies that the referred object might have a subtype of `X` without the need to worry about it.

You can simply use the base class `BarIf` here, regardless of which actual subtype of `BarIf` the object has:

```
BarIf bar = newRandomBarImpl();
FooIf<BarIf> foo=newFooBar(BarIf.class);
foo.doSomething(bar);
```

Note that when you want to use methods of the actual implementation type `Foo`, not specified in the interface, you will have to cast the `FooIf` to `Foo`. You can cast a `FooIf<BarIf>` to `Foo<BarIf>` without a warning as the generic type conversion is correct if `Foo<X> implements FooIf<X>`.

However, it can fail at runtime as the method `newFooBar` is not required to return an instance of `Foo` rather than any other implementation of `FooIf`. That’s why an explicit type cast is the only correct solution as it documents that there is an assumption made about the actual runtime type of an object. All other attempts will generate at least one compiler warning somewhere.

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thank you. I guess I had my generics messed up.